# Neo4J Community Edition Calling Home?

Tags: neo4j

while working on our Neo4J graph application And setting debug logging for the root logger I came across the following statistics like message:

```
[DEBUG] HttpURLConnection: sun.net.www.MessageHeader@537f294a7 pairs: {GET /?totalmem=12758278144+propids=0+os.arch=amd64+edition=community+dist=unknown+source=maven+numprocs=4+mac=005056c00008+revision=2.1.5:2.1-maint:529/45c3cc04946c2b0e243e48c8252e40cb85931744+tags=spring,sdn,web+os.version=6.3+reg=unreg+relids=0+v=2.1.5+heapsize=47775896+os.name=Windows_8.1+id=641ca9a78ddc53ae+labelids=3+nodeids=0+p=-1 HTTP/1.1: null}{Cache-Control: no-cache}{Pragma: no-cache}{User-Agent: Java/1.8.0_51}{Host: 52.0.233.188}{Accept: text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2}{Connection: keep-alive}
[DEBUG] HttpURLConnection: sun.net.www.MessageHeader@167dbd419 pairs: {null: HTTP/1.1 200 OK}{Server: nginx/1.6.2}{Date: Sun, 30 Aug 2015 10:05:40 GMT}{Content-Type: text/html}{Content-Length: 164}{Last-Modified: Fri, 01 Jun 2012 09:48:29 GMT}{Connection: keep-alive}{ETag: "4fc88fed-a4"}{Accept-Ranges: bytes}
```

I'm more than a little surprised because I haven't configured anything in Neo4j that tells it to share my machine configuration with some web server on the internets.

By the way, I know it is neo4j due to the version number (2.1.5) and community edition keywords, and the ip number 52.0.233.188 which resolves to an amazon aws dns entry but identifies itself as udc.neo4j.org.

Comment: Anonymous downvotes? Really? I would be curious as to a reason for the downvote.

Comment: Hey, you're correct. Neo4j has been always quite open about it. When we introduced the feature we had a long blog post and it is described in full detail in the manual. I also upvoted your posts to counter that anonymous downvoter :)

Comment: Ha thanks for the counter vote! But why not an [INFO] message telling the user that this is enabled at boot? I know I wouldn't mind it at all when told explicitly during regular usage. It just surprised me during debug.

Answer (score 3):

I've discovered that this is a by-default-on Usage Data Collector service that Neo4j documents here:
http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/usage-data-collector.html

It contains details about how to disable it also.. Having said that, I really don't like this kind of stuff getting more and more prevalent in software nowadays.

**UPDATE 1:**
I've tried to disable the udc by following the steps described (http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/usage-data-collector.html#_how_to_disable_udc), but the UDC is still contacted. This is running from my Eclipse IDE, haven't tested yet with packaged fat jar:

```
[DEBUG] HttpURLConnection: sun.net.www.MessageHeader@32bc2cb97 pairs: {GET /?totalmem=42932072448+propids=1323+os.arch=amd64+edition=community+dist=unknown+source=maven+numprocs=24+mac=005056c00008+revision=2.1.8:2.1-maint:687/5c83ce3a5ddf33259593f719153ce71a6fe89fc7+tags=spring,sdn,web+os.version=6.3+reg=unreg+relids=810+v=2.1.8+heapsize=156271600+os.name=Windows_8.1+id=b599d44d76a45a87+labelids=10+nodeids=409+p=-1 HTTP/1.1: null}{Cache-Control: no-cache}{Pragma: no-cache}{User-Agent: Java/1.8.0_51}{Host: 52.0.233.188}{Accept: text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2}{Connection: keep-alive}
[DEBUG] HttpURLConnection: sun.net.www.MessageHeader@77bea48a9 pairs: {null: HTTP/1.1 200 OK}{Server: nginx/1.6.2}{Date: Mon, 31 Aug 2015 11:05:30 GMT}{Content-Type: text/html}{Content-Length: 164}{Last-Modified: Fri, 01 Jun 2012 09:48:29 GMT}{Connection: keep-alive}{ETag: "4fc88fed-a4"}{Accept-Ranges: bytes}
```

Comment: Another anonymous downvote? So: I raise a genuine issue, and my reputation in the sense of points on stack overflow is downgraded, and no reason is given for the downvote. That seems unfair.

Comment: Did you disable using config or by pulling out the UDC jar?

Comment: I've disabled by excluding UDC.jar; we're running 2.1.8 atm, and we still see Neo4J connecting. We've enabled a firewall rule to block it.. rather disappointingly.

Comment: I'm surprised that you find it still calls out after excluding the UDC jar. That is definitely not working as expected and we'd consider it a serious bug. I wonder if it's something strange about your Eclipse configuration. Is there any chance of your trying to reproduce with the downloaded product (e.g http://neo4j.com/download-thanks/?edition=community&release=2.1.8&flavour=unix&_ga=1.169780705.114495776.1411120235).